# server error while dispatching from servlet to jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to log number of visits to any resource in my web app:
Here's my class:

```
public class FullTracking extends HttpServlet
{
 Hashtable<String,Integer> links=new Hashtable<>();

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws 
 ServletException,IOException{
   String uri=req.getRequestURI();
   String resource=uri.substring(req.getContextPath().length(),uri.length());

  if(links.containsKey(resource)){
    Integer count=links.get(resource);
    links.put(resource,new Integer(1+count.intValue()));
  }
  else{
    links.put(resource,new Integer(1));
  }
  req.setAttribute("links",links);
  req.getRequestDispatcher("/FullTracking.jsp").forward(req,res);
}
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws 
  ServletException,IOException{
   doGet(req,res);
  }
}
```

The FullTracking.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.tests.FullTracking,java.util.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
key/value pairs:<br/>
<c:forEach var="r" items="${links}">
${r.key}:${r.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>FullTracking</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.tests.FullTracking</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FullTracking</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I visit any resource with the present mapping I get an Inernal server error (500), and a lengthy stack trace ending with a root cause of java.lang.StackOverflowError caused by

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/FullTracking.jsp").forward(req,res);
```

If I change the mapping in web.xml to say:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FullTracking</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/tracker/*</url-pattern>
</servet-mapping>
```

There's no error, but the results are not what I expect.
For learning purpose: I want to understand the link between the dispatching and the java.lang.StackOverflowError.

```
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.tests.FullTracking.doGet(FullTracking.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)

Root Cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getMethod(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:123)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getMethod(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:123)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:628)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.tests.FullTracking.doGet(FullTracking.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.tests.FullTracking.doGet(FullTracking.java:24)
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I understood where the `java.lang.StackOverflowError` comes from. In fact the request is caught by the servlet because of the mapping, then from inside the dispatcher forwards to the jsp through the same mapping, which is again caught by the servlet and so on.
My question now is about a way to tell the dispatcher not to go through the mapping when it forwards to the JSP?

Comment: Post the exception message?

Comment: @YatiSawhney I cannot post the full stack trace, it's 68 000 chars. the body can't exceed 30 000 chars.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Dispatcher is looking for JSP at the wrong place.

From the info you have provided I could figure out the URL of your servlet which is like you updated your web.xml:

```
http://localhost:8080/<rootContext>/tracker
```

Now, `req.getRequestDispatcher("/FullTracking.jsp").forward(req,res);` will look for the jsp in `http://localhost:8080/<rootContext>/`. 
Make sure the jsp is present at this location.

As, far as your problem is concerned this will not give you the exact count as you program is **NOT** `ThreadSafe` Lock your map so that only one can access it at a time

```
private Hashtable<String,AtomicInteger> links=new Hashtable<>();

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        String resource = uri.substring(req.getContextPath().length(), uri.length());

        synchronized (links) {

            if (links.containsKey(resource)) {
                AtomicInteger count = links.get(resource).incrementAndGet();
                links.put(resource, count);
            } else {
                links.put(resource, new AtomicInteger(1));
            }

        }
        req.setAttribute("links", links);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/FullTracking.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't keep the change to web.xml, and JSP is at the root of web app.

Comment: Where is your jsp present?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Check your context-root in server.xml in case tomcat is your container

Comment: tomcat 8.5.27 is the container I am using. I didn't configure context root in server.xml for any web app testing before.

Comment: If you are using any ide eclipse or netbeans it would have done it for you